# rails and bootstrap with custom fonts?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am trying to learn how to use custom fonts however I keep getting a jquery error I think it is? while trying to load the fonts.

It's this error here:

> jquery.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1:3735 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/fonts/dayslater/dayslater.ttf

I have added this line inside application.rb:

```
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

my css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'dayslater';
  src: url('fonts/dayslater/dayslater.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

please note that these bits of CSS are in different files but even in the same file they do not work.

```
#dayslat {
  font: 3em 'dayslater';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

I was just wondering why it will not work thank you

Comment: `ttf` is used for Safari, Android, IOS. what about another browsers?

Comment: I'm currently learning how to install the fonts and make them work, so I can make fall-backs as well :)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ this article was very useful fo me)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working, thanks to Igor.

He pointed out that instead of having

```
font: 3em 'dayslater';
```

It should instead be:

```
font-family: 'dayslater';
font-size: 3em;
```

and also adding this line in application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

however what the problem was, rails now automatically detects font files, 
so when I had

> fonts/--font folder--/font.ttf

It should have been:

> --font folder--/font.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dayslat {
  font-family: 'dayslater';
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

add in `application.rb` below string:

```
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

in your `css` use:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: normal;
}
```

with your own font-name

Comment: Nope, no error at the moment that sort of comes and goes however the actual font never changed.

Comment: Just done that now and still nothing has changed yet.